# How can you preset the IP address (and other parameters) of a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: networking

When we download the RPi operating system (anyone of them) images, is there a way to preset the RPi unit so that it takes a certain IP address?

Right now, my router leases IP addresses via DHCP, and so when I copy the OS image to the SD card, I have to hook up a keyboard and monitor to each RPi to log in and manually set the IP to a static IP.

I am building a cluster of RPi's and as I keep adding nodes, I have to repeat this cumbersome task for each new node.

Also, any way to preset the host name is also helpful.

Is there some software that can administer a cluster of RPi's? Assume I have a closed network RPi cluster (all nodes linked by a simple switch), can I setup a "master" node that will automatically setup the newly added nodes?

Answer (score 2):

If you search this Forum you will find hundreds of posts about setting static IP including setting in `/boot/cmdline.txt`. I would recommend you don't do this, rather reserve in your router.

There is no easy way to preset host name, but it is stored in `/etc/hostname`, and you could set this if you mount the FS. I use a simple script to copy to this file.

Comment: Thanks, I think that static IP will approach might work, this will be a closed network/cluster of RPi's. When you use a script to manipulate the hostname, how do you know the IP a priori? I assume you use something like scp to copy the file?

Comment: I only have a couple of Pi, so I run manually. I did think of writing an automatic based on MAC, but decided it wasn't worth the effort. I mount using ssh to run.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. You might want to look at my project Nard SDK which has what you seek. Here is a link to the documentation explaining how to preset the SDcard static IP and host name with any standard Windows PC.

http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard/#devsettings